# some HTTPS sites getting blocked on one machine in network

Tags: blocking, https, windows-firewall

I have a few computers connected to the internet via a router. I have been having some trouble with this one Windows 7 desktop. I can browse most of the sites without any trouble but some sites where the sign in page switches to a secure connection (https), the page does not load. It's not all of the sites though. I'm able to sign into gmail and a few other services that I know use https . The sites I'm having trouble with; yahoo's sign in page and the one that I have been using to test across different systems, 
http://iforgot.apple.com (which switchs to https) ;this particular site, i can access from other computers on the network and my phone.

I only have windows firewall running and AVG. I even tried to stopping windows firewall but it did not help.

Everything was fine last week. All I have installed in the past week is VOIP softwares namely skype, ooVoo and windows live messenger. I'm not sure how to find out what's being blocked and why and how to unblock it? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
Using Fiddler, I captured this for http://iforgot.apple.com

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Connection failed
Connection: close
Timestamp: 10:47:53.508

HTTPS connection failed.

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 17.254.2.152:443
   at Fiddler.ServerChatter.CreateConnectedSocket(IPAddress[] arrDestIPs, Int32 iPort, Session _oSession)
   at Fiddler.Session._handleHTTPSConnect()
```

Comment: what software do you use to browse internet? firefox, ie, opera?

Comment: Primarily chrome, but i have tried firefox and IE too, with same results.

Comment: glad to hear you resolved the problem.  Add an answer to your question mentioning what fixed it and mark it as Accepted.  This will prevent anyone else trying to answer who does not read your comment to Mandeep's post and see that it's already fixed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue with my router. I got a new wireless router and I haven't had that issue since.